# Как подключить библиотеку в проекте на С++

Tags: c++

Как подключить библиотеку в проекте на С++

https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Usage-examples

Comment: Какую IDE используете?

Comment: @Александр  VS 2012 Express

Answer (score 3):

При использование Visual Studio: самый простой — в любом файле добавить запись:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "<путь к lib файлу>")
```

Как альтернатива, можно указать lib-файл в свойствах проекта, для этого перейдите к пункту:

1. <kbd>Linker → General → Additional Library Directories</kbd> — указать каталог с lib-файлов.(напр. D:\ace\lib)
2. <kbd>Linker → Input → Additional Dependencies</kbd> — указать само название lib файла (напр. ace_vc11.lib)

Так же в <kbd>C/C++ → General → Additional Include Directories</kbd> можно указать путь к *.h файлам, чтоб в своих исходниках не прописывать полный путь на диске.

**Update**:

Если библиотека из себя представляет только h-файл(такое возможно), тогда достаточно просто написать:

```
#include "<путь к h файлу>"
```

и далее пользоваться предоставленным функционалом.

Но в основном библиотека представляет из себя `*.lib`-файл и `*.h`-файлы, необходимые для сборки своего приложения а также непосредственно `*.dll`-файл, необходимый для запуска приложения.

Comment: У меня нет lib файла. Есть только h файл

Comment: @SVD102 обновил ответ

Comment: Ошибка 1 error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: hpdf.h: No such file or directory c:\users\виктор\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\etc_1\etc_1\main.cpp 2 1 ETC_1

Comment: @SVD102 переместите файл в каталог с более коротким путем и без кириллических символов. D:\include\hpdf.h. Очевидно, что данная библиотека не будет собираться без lib файлов.

Comment: Почему так, это ведь не удобно

Comment: Вы можете попробовать подключить эту библиотеку, которую я скинул.

Comment: Переместил файл в каталог с более коротким путем и без кириллических символов, но все так же.