# Проблема с поключением заголовочных файлов в Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Я хочу написать программу с использованием Windows Forms и у меня есть заголовочный файл с нужными мне функциями. Но при подключении его получаю ошибку:

```
1>MyForm.obj : error LNK2005: "unsigned long __cdecl get_module(char * const,unsigned long const &)" (?get_module@@YAKQADABK@Z) уже определен в bhop.obj
1>MyForm.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl bhop(unsigned long &,void * &)" (?bhop@@YAXAAKAAPAX@Z) уже определен в bhop.obj
1>MyForm.obj : error LNK2005: "unsigned long __cdecl get_module(char * const,unsigned long const &)" (?get_module@@$$FYAKQADABK@Z) уже определен в bhop.obj
1>MyForm.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl bhop(unsigned long &,void * &)" (?bhop@@$$FYAXAAKAAPAX@Z) уже определен в bhop.obj
1>MyForm.obj : error LNK2028: ссылка на неразрешенную лексему (0A00004C) "extern "C" short __stdcall GetAsyncKeyState(int)" (?GetAsyncKeyState@@$$J14YGFH@Z) в функции "void __cdecl bhop(unsigned long &,void * &)" (?bhop@@$$FYAXAAKAAPAX@Z)
1>MyForm.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "extern "C" short __stdcall GetAsyncKeyState(int)" (?GetAsyncKeyState@@$$J14YGFH@Z) в функции "void __cdecl bhop(unsigned long &,void * &)" (?bhop@@$$FYAXAAKAAPAX@Z).
1>C:\Users\artem\source\repos\bhop_ui\Debug\bhop_ui.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 2
1>Сборка проекта "bhop_ui.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
```

Не могли бы вы подсказать каким образом нужно оформить заголовочный файл, чтобы можно было подключить без ошибок.

P. s. Подключаю в файле Form.h

```
#pragma once

#include "bhop.h"
#include "bhop.cpp"

namespace bhopui {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
...
```

Содержимое файла bhop.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

#define dwLocalPlayer 0xD8722C
#define dwForceJump 0x52489A4
#define m_fFlags  0x104

DWORD get_module(const LPSTR module_name, const DWORD& process_id);
void bhop(DWORD& client, HANDLE& hProcess);
```

Содержимое bhop.cpp:

```
#pragma once

#include "bhop.h"

DWORD get_module(const LPSTR module_name, const DWORD& process_id)
{
    HANDLE module_snapshot = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    module_snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, process_id);

    if (module_snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CloseHandle(module_snapshot);
        return 0;
    }

    MODULEENTRY32 module_entry;
    module_entry.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

    if (Module32First(module_snapshot, &module_entry))
        if (!strcmp(module_name, module_entry.szModule))
        {
            CloseHandle(module_snapshot);
            return (DWORD)(module_entry.modBaseAddr);
        }

    while (Module32Next(module_snapshot, &module_entry))
    {
        if (!strcmp(module_name, module_entry.szModule))
        {
            CloseHandle(module_snapshot);
            return (DWORD)(module_entry.modBaseAddr);
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(module_snapshot);
    return 0;
}

void bhop(DWORD& client, HANDLE& hProcess)
{
        DWORD local_player;
        int flags;
        const int fj = 6;

        while (true)
        {
            ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)(client + dwLocalPlayer), &local_player, sizeof(local_player), NULL);
            ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)(local_player + m_fFlags), &flags, sizeof(flags), NULL);

            if (flags == 257 && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x8000)
            {
                WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)(client + dwForceJump), &fj, sizeof(fj), NULL);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: 1) почему не пользуетесь `namespace`? 2) а что у вас в MyForm.cpp?

Comment: зачем `#include "bhop.cpp"`?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, но в "bhop.cpp" реализация функций "get_module" и "bhop", разве не надо этот файл подключать?

Comment: достаточно добавить `.h`- header

Comment: @n1kzzz А вы знаете зачем нужны хидера и source файлы?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, насколько мне известно в хедерах обычно лежат прототипы функций и подключения других заголовочных файлов, а в соурс файлах лежит реализация функций, но могу ошибаться ибо я новичок.

Comment: @n1kzzz все верно, ну а теперь подумайте сами: а зачем вы включаете и прототип и реализацию?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, извините я скорее всего немного не понимаю про протототипы функций, в моем понимании прототип функции указывает компилятору, что ниже лежит определенная функция и не более. Соответственно при подключении h-файла нам мы только сообщим компилятору о таких то функциях, но самой реализации у нас не будет, поэтому я подключаю еще cpp-файл. Я так понимаю это не совсем верно, поэтому можете дать ссылку на доп. литературу про прототипы функций.

Comment: [заголовочные файлы](https://ravesli.com/urok-21-zagolovochnye-fajly/)

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, спасибо, но хотелось бы еще уточнить про прототипы функций, а именно: как они работают. Просто я до сих пор не могу понять, каким образом при подключении только header-файла компилятор понимает о каких функциях идёт речь, ведь мы даже не подключаем файл с реализацией этих функций, а следовательно компилятор не может знать о их реализации.

Comment: [единица трансляции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: @n1kzzz вы не понимаете этого потому, что полностью зависите от ide. Я так понимаю вы работаете в visual studio и добавляя новый файл к проекту делаете просто через интерфейс ide даже не понимая а что в этот момент происходит? Советую хотя бы временно откпзаться от ide и самому написать Makefile или CMakeLists.txt и у вас больше не возникнет вопросов: а как это работает (заодно и узнаете что есть такая вещь как линкер, что такое make и чем крут cmake)

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, извините, можете пожалуйста ответить на предыдущий вопрос про прототипы функций.

Comment: @n1kzzz, прототипы нужны для разрешения имен, чтобы знать как вызывать, но реализация не нужна, реализация лежит в другом [объектном модуле](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C)(единице трансляции). Попробуйте ручками подключить какую-нибудь библиотеку для которой есть хедер, но нет файла срр. "Ручками" это значит через командную строку.

Comment: @n1kzzz, применительно к вашему примеру, компилятор создает объектные модули bhop.obj и Form.obj, а линковщик собирает в конце эти модули непосредственно в программу exe. Вся эта работа спрятана за IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Увидев [ошибку линкера](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2005?view=msvc-160), я понял, что здесь повторное включение кода.

```
 error LNK2005: "unsigned long __cdecl get_module(char * const,unsigned long const &)" (?get_module@@YAKQADABK@Z) уже определен в bhop.obj
```

И действительно, в файле `Form.h` есть дополнительное включение файла `.cpp`, что не есть хорошо - обычно исходники не включаются в заголовочные файлы. При компиляции создаются `Form.obj` и `bhop.obj` с реализацией из `bhop.cpp`. Они создаются компилятором, но линкер(компоновщик) ругается потому, что происходит конфликт имен(прототипов, сигнатур) - и в первом и во втором объектном модуле функции с одинаковыми именами. Вот собственно в этом и проблема. Лечится удалением `#include "bhop.cpp"`.

Но это еще не все.

```
error LNK2028: ссылка на неразрешенную лексему (0A00004C) "extern "C" short __stdcall GetAsyncKeyState(int)" (?GetAsyncKeyState@@$$J14YGFH@Z) в функции "void __cdecl bhop(unsigned long &,void * &)" (?bhop@@$$FYAXAAKAAPAX@Z)
```

Данная ошибка говорит, что не подлючена библиотека `user32.lib` в которой присутствует функция [GetAsyncKeyState](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate).
Подключить можно через директиву компилятора `#pragma`, либо через настройку линкера(предпочтительнее). Более подробнее [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597165/281034).

Comment: Удалил ' #include"bhop.cpp" '. Все равно выдает ошибку 'ссылка на неразрешенную лексему ... GetAsyncKeyState()' (как в вопросе на 5 строке).

Comment: Вот же ж как, несколько проблем. Эта ошибка от линкера говорит, что вы подключили хедеры, но не подключили библиотеки(набор объектных модулей). Нужно подключить библиотеку в которой находится GetAsyncKeyState.

Comment: Так GetAsyncKeyState() в Windows.h, а это стандартная библиотека.

Comment: ДА, СПАСИБО! А почему вы сделали это через #pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib"), а не через #include, напрмер?

Comment: [добавьте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781554/9210255) `#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")`.  [GetAsyncKeyState](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate?redirectedfrom=MSDN) лежит в user32.lib. Вместо `pragma` лучше добавить библиотеку в проект. Помогло?

Comment: user32.lib - это бинарный файл(в нем уже реализация), а через `include` добавляется текстовой файл с прототипами(именами).

Comment: @n1kzzz, обновил ответ.