# Как установить библиотеку libnoise для c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Хочу сделать процедурную генерацию мира в консоли(должно по идее выглядеть как мир майнкрафта с высоты). Для этого хочу использовать алгоритм "Шум Перлина" для того чтобы делать "фундамент" для мира, а затем окрашивать его. У меня возникла такая проблема - "Не могу понять как подключить библиотеку libnoise". Библиотеку нашел [здесь](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial2.html).

Я прикрепил фото как выглядит папка с библиотекой

[image].

Comment: А зачем писать роботу? Он не [ответит.](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/tutorials/tutorial1.html)

Comment: Немного не понял сути. Можешь пожалуйста объяснить?

Comment: У меня VS 19. То что есть в той инструкции у меня просто такого нету

Comment: https://ravesli.com/podklyuchenie-i-ispolzovanie-bibliotek-v-visual-studio-2017/

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/597154/281034

Comment: А если у меня в папке и include и lib только по одному файлу и они называются - "Makefaile" ?

Comment: Значит надо собрать библиотеку, а потом подключать к вашему проекту.

Comment: Как собрать библиотеку?

Comment: есть же [бинарники и хедеры](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libnoise/files/)

Comment: Это точно такая библиотека как и у меня

Comment: Вы же говорили, что там нет include и lib. Они там есть. Алгоритм установки  библиотеки есть в инете, берите любой и устанавливайте.

Comment: Я совсем запутался. Зачем сайте выкладывать библиотеку в которой ничего нету ? И  все эти файлы нужно скачивать по отдельности и закидывать в эту библиотеку. Как-то нелогично

Comment: Вы можете собрать сами библиотеку, или воспользоваться уже готовым. Я вижу, что вы не разу не подключали библиотеки. Попробуйте найти любую другую библиотеку с актуальным пошаговым алгоритмом установки подходящим для вашей IDE. Не забывайте, что IDE это всего лишь обертка для работы с компилятором.

Comment: Я уже 2 дня ищу какую-либо другую библиотеку с шумом Перлина. Я всегда натыкаюсь на ту, которая у меня сейчас

Comment: Я имею ввиду любую, даже не относящуюся к вашей задаче. Вам просто нужно научиться подключать библиотеки.

Comment: Я смотрел на сайт который вы скидывали(revesly). Если бы эта библиотека была по типу которая указан там, у меня не было бы никаких проблем. Я просто  не могу понять почему в С++ библиотеки так отличаются. Одни просто с dll файлами - другие совсем наобарот.

Comment: Любую библиотеку можно представить в статическом или динамическом виде. Вам [сюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8), чтобы понять разницу.